# How to detect if input does not match any of the output options

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

How would I accurately identify the results of a prediction to determine if the input was a match or if the input was completely difference to any of the training data.

For example, if I've got a model which identifies "circles", "squares" and other shapes but then the user inputted a "squiggle of mess", how would I stop it accidentally matching the highest probability?

My knowlege is relatively low, currently my model looks like this.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               262656
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 100)               25700
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 505
=================================================================
Total params: 420,189
Trainable params: 420,189
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Then when making a prediction I use `np.argmax` to get the highest probability.

I came to this layout by trial and error from watching and reading a range of resources. Guidance for this too is very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, softmax can still help. It is an approximation, not an exact unit-step function. You can always check the difference between the two highest terms, and threshold it to check if multiple shapes are present.

For example, if the input contains all three shapes, the ideal output of softmax would be:

```
[0.3333 0.3333 0.3333]
```

Considering a relatively well-trained model, the output may be something like:

```
[0.34, 0.30, 0.36]
```

For an input with only one shape, the result would be very different. It may be something like:

```
[0.9999, 1e-6, 2e-6]
```

In all these cases, you can use the difference between the most probable element and second-most probable element to identify a "squiggle of mess". Alternatively, you can also threshold the output of softmax itself, for example, to say that a softmax value > 0.9 indicats a shape, anything lower is invalid input.

Keep in mind, these are still approximations, and may result in some errors. The entire process is highly dependent on how well your model actually performs.